# "TemplateSyntaxError Invalid block tag: 'trans'" error in Django Templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates, translation, templatetags

After running the `runserver` command I get the following error:

> **TemplateSyntaxError at /questions/ Invalid block tag: 'trans'**

Does anybody know that what's the reason?

This is my template syntax:

```
{% extends "two_column_body.html" %}
{# 
    this template is split into several
    blocks that are included here
    the blocks are within directory templates/main_page
    relative to the skin directory

    there is no html markup in this file
#}
<!-- questions.html -->
{% block forejs %}
    {% include "main_page/custom_head_javascript.html" %}
{% endblock %}
{% block title %}{% spaceless %}{% trans %}Questions{% endtrans %}{% endspaceless %}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    {% include "main_page/tab_bar.html" %}
    {% include "main_page/headline.html" %}
    {# ==== BEGIN: main_page/content.html === #}
    <div id="question-list">
        {% include "main_page/questions_loop.html" %}
    </div>
    {# ==== END: main_page/content.html === #}
    {% include "main_page/paginator.html" %}
{% endblock %}
{% block sidebar %}
    {% include "main_page/sidebar.html" %}
{% endblock %}
{% block endjs %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        {# cant cache this #}
        askbot['settings']['showSortByRelevance'] = {{ show_sort_by_relevance|as_js_bool }};
        askbot['messages']['questionSingular'] = '{{ settings.WORDS_QUESTION_SINGULAR|escapejs }}';
        askbot['messages']['answerSingular'] = '{{ settings.WORDS_ANSWER_SINGULAR|escapejs }}';
        askbot['messages']['acceptOwnAnswer'] = '{{ settings.WORDS_ACCEPT_OR_UNACCEPT_OWN_ANSWER|escapejs }}';
        askbot['messages']['followQuestions'] = '{{ settings.WORDS_FOLLOW_QUESTIONS|escapejs }}';
    </script>
    {% include "main_page/javascript.html" %}
    {% include "main_page/custom_javascript.html" %}
{% endblock %}
<!-- end questions.html -->
```

Comment: Did you forget to `{% load i18n %}`?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`{% trans %}Questions{% endtrans %}` is not the correct format.

`{% load i18n %}` should be at the top of your template, or any extended template using translations.

You can use `{% trans "Questions." %}`

If  you're going to use blocks, they need to be in the format below:

```
{% blocktrans %}{{ value2translate }}{% endblocktrans %}
```

More info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#trans-template-tag).

Comment: Have you checked the other templates?  Could you please provide the output from the debug file?

Comment: `{% load i18n %}` should be at the top of current template.**and all extended templates** !!! 

also must use `{% blocktrans %}Qusetion{% endblocktrans %}` instead `{% rans %}Qusetion{% endtrans %}`

thanks for your help !

Comment: Glad you got it working.  I'll update the answer to clarify the `{% load i1in %}` part.

Comment: the link is not valid any longer, please edit or remove the reference link

Answer (score 5):

Probably you should use `{% blocktrans %}Questions{% endblocktrans %}` and you forget to put `{% load i18n %}` toward the top of your template.

Comment: try to use `{% blocktrans %}Questions{% endblocktrans %}` instead of `{% trans %}Questions{% endtrans %}` or `{% trans "Questions" %}` and remove `{% endtrans %}`

Answer (score 3):

this is because you have not loaded i18n in this template`{% load i18n %}` you must add this in each of your template.

Answer (score 2):

You must place at the beginning of your extended template code: `{% load i18n %}` , so you can use the trans Tags:

```
{% extends 'home/base.html' %}

{% block title %}INICIO{% endblock %}
{% load i18n %}


  {% block opcionesMenu %}
<!-- =====START====== -->
            <a href="#sTop" class="subNavBtn">{% trans "Inicio"  %}</a>
            <a href="#s1" class="subNavBtn">{% trans "Proyectos" %}</a>
            <a href="#s2" class="subNavBtn">{% trans "Diseño Web" %}</a>
            <a href="#s3" class="subNavBtn">{% trans "Marketing" %}</a>
            <a href="#s4" class="subNavBtn">{% trans "Conocenos" %}</a>
            <a href="#s5" class="subNavBtn">{% trans "Contacto" %}</a>
<!-- =====END ====== -->
 {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers, you need to put [{% load i18n %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-template-code) after [{% extends %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#std-templatetag-extends) to use [{% trans %} or {% translate %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/translation/#translate-template-tag) as shown below:

```
{% extends "two_column_body.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
```

`{% extends %}` is explained in [Template inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance) as shown below:

- If you use `{% extends %}` in a template, it must be the first template tag in that template. Template inheritance won’t work, otherwise.

So, if you put `{% load i18n %}` before `{% extends %}` as shown below:

```
{% load i18n %}
{% extends "two_column_body.html" %}
```

Then, the error below occurs:

> <ExtendsNode: extends "..."> must be the first tag in the template.